# Reorder fragments inside fragmentManager

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

Let's say I observe a fragmentsTag list as follows: **[A, B, C]**

My goal is to display these fragments in this order (in my case in a `linearLayout`).

so i can do this :

```
childFragmentManager.fragmentTransaction {
   add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentTag)
}
```

Now let's say that the order of the fragments changes and that I choose to hide fragment B. So I am notified in my liveData with a new list of fragmentsTag as follows : **[C, A]**

How do I display these fragments in this order in my LinearLayout? And hide the old fragment B.

Note that I want to reuse instances of fragments **[A, B, C]** that are already in the `fragmentManager`. So no new `FragmentManager.add()`

so I use `fragmentManager.hide(fragment)` and `fragmentManager.show(fragment)`... However, I can't keep order.

Answer (score 0):

I clear all the view from the LinearLayout and i have added dynamically fragments to linearLayout each time liveData is updated. That seems like a solution that's temporary to me.